# select left join except one column

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

i have select:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* from t1 left join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

when id exist or not exist in t2 I want all columns from t2 except t2.id (which can be NULL).

Is there any way do this without print out all columns names in query?

thx

Comment: hm, either I did not understand what you were asking, or you have not checked yourself the other answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to either specify all columns of interest or use a wildcard.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
  USING (id);
```

That is, by the way, the reason, why it is a good idea to name the columns that you are going to use in joins the same way across the database.

Comment: yes .. you are right .. with USING mysql remove duplicate column ID .. but whe u use t1.id ,t1.name, t2.*, t3.* does not work anymore and duplicate column ID is back :(

Comment: @mort, well, that is another case: now you explicitly say that you want all columns from the `t2` table. Anyway, it is a good idea to specify all columns explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If the two tables have only `id` as a common column, you can also use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  t1 
  NATURAL LEFT JOIN
      t2
```

Comment: might be dangerous if there are homonymous columns he would not like to join on

Comment: Also, it will return `t1`'s `id`.

Comment: @Quassnoi, it seems from the question that the OP does not want `t2.id` in the output, but does want `t1.id`

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the order of requested tables
instead

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* from t1 left join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

use

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.* from t1 left join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Occur With "ID" Now you can do like this:

```
"SELECT task.*, users.emp_id,users.emp_name,users.emp_designation from task
 LEFT JOIN users ON task.userid=users.id where users.sup_id='1021' AND task.date='2022-09-03'"
```

here i will get the task table id and all data & users table 3 column . easy and simple